# Custom Brushes in Java

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to develop A paint program that I can use for when I am bored. I am trying to figure out how I would be able to customize a brushed for the graphics component. Is making a custom brush possible? thanks again.

Comment: Could you show what code you have working?  I expect this is very doable but can be done in several ways depending on the API that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check *JHLabs Java Image Processing* which it is a good resource for image filters. It Also contains some custom brush codes which it will be useful to begin with strokes in java.

The current links below are available at the time of answering this questions:

Check this: http://www.jhlabs.com/ie/index.html

and this: http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html

and for you question: http://www.jhlabs.com/java/java2d/strokes/

Comment: In fact creating brushes like what you see in Photoshop, requites lots of Math calculations for pressure, etc.

Comment: Be careful using links for the entirety of your answers. If somebody ever needs to look at this question in the future, and the links are dead, then this question is useless.

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas, I will add some descriptions then :)